# Cache php calls on client side

Tags: nginx, php, caching

I own a website hosted on a debian 7 machine running nginx.
When a user logs in, I serve him a lot of generated by php. Some of these files are always the same.

Is there a method to cache them on a client browser, and then when the client ask these files, respond with a 304 not modified?

I use php-fpm, on nginx1.6, with only https.

Comment: `some of the files that i serve with php however are always the same` - why server them via php at all then? In any event the/one answer to your question is to set appropriate expire headers - so that clients _don't_ request anything that they've already requested and cached client-side.

Comment: Web content can be cached (by client or a proxy) if the server marks marks it as cacheable.

Comment: i serve them via php because the files are different from user to user @AD7six

Comment: is it possible to mark .php cacheable? @HBruijn

Comment: Simply by setting the correct cache control headers from php